# sumif range and criteria switching

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

So I have a table of number of fiscal weeks in a year, and to calculate depreciation I'm trying to sum the number of weeks in the total life of the capital investment. So the first argument is the range, the second argument pulls the year from another cell, and then adds the expected life in years of the device. The third argument is the intended sum range.

`SUMIF(YearWeeks[Year],"<="&LEFT(AS$14,4)+$H20,YearWeeks[Weeks])`

This works fine. Pulls in the right numbers no problem.
However, whenever I try and drag this across other cells so that it can be used throughout my spreadsheet to caculate depreciation, it immediately switches the value for year and the value for weeks and becomes:

`SUMIF(YearWeeks[Weeks],"<="&LEFT(AU$14,4)+$H20,YearWeeks[Year])`

I cannot figure out why it is doing this. It is probably something simple, but it is completely evading me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

`Year   Weeks
2015    52
2016    53
2017    52
2018    52
2019    52
2020    52
2021    53
2022    52
2023    52
2024    52
2025    52
2026    52
2027    53
2028    52
2029    52
2030    52`

```
Life

5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
8
8
8
8
8
8

201504  201505  201506  201507  201508  201509  201510  201511  201512  201601  201602  201603
```

Comment: Instead of dragging the formula to the right, copy the cell and paste it in the cell right to it, etc...

Comment: `201504  201505  201506  201507  201508  201509  201510  201511  201512  201601  201602` that's row 14? So you do want the column to change. What's `YearWeeks[Year]`?

Comment: Yes, that is row 14. YearWeeks is the name of the first table with the two headers

Comment: Instead of using named ranges/tables, just use the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dragging the formula to the right, copy the cell and paste it in the cell at the right of it, etc... :

This will keep the column references unchanged (no change from `YearWeeks[Weeks]` to `YearWeeks[Year]`).

As specified on [Microsoft's support website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-a547e45e-3589-4417-b611-abb7e5d3f912):

> **Moving, copying, and filling structured references**
>
> All structured references remain the same when you copy or move a formula that uses a structured reference.
>
> When you fill a formula, fully qualified structured references can adjust the column specifiers like a series as summarized in the following table.

NB: `YearWeeks[Weeks]` is a structured reference, and *fill* is what many would call *drag* in this context.

Comment: That's gotta be tedious XD

Comment: Well you can copy in one go: select one cell, copy it, then select range of 10 cells next to it, paste.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I'll have to read through this to understand WHY on earth they would set it like this.

Comment: I guess I don't have any structured references.

Comment: @findwindow, for unstructured references like for example `F10`: put a dollar sign before the `F` to fix it. Then drag happily to the right: it remains an `F`.